# REACT: Add highlighted border around selected image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want a border around the picture when I select it. So if I have 6 pictures and choose 3, I would like to have highlighted borders around those images. Question is,How can I do this? EDIT: I am using React for this dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you want to track state in your app.. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ss85wcrq/2/) is an example which tracks the state in the parent component. Essentially you have a single parent App component which tracks the state for each image, and then an Image component which renders either with or without a border, depending on a piece of the App state which gets passed down as a prop. Refer to the code to see what I mean. An alternative would be to have the active state live within each Image component itself.

The code has a number of interesting features mainly due to leveraging several aspects of ES6 to be more concise, as well as [React's immutability helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) to help update the state array in an immutable way, and lodash's [times](https://lodash.com/docs#times) method to assist in creating our initial state array.

Code (some of the indenting got a bit muddled in the copy from jsfiddle..):

```
function getImage() {
    return { active: false };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { images: _.times(6, getImage) };
    this.clickImage = this.clickImage.bind(this);
  }
  clickImage(ix) {
    const images = React.addons.update(this.state.images, {
      [ix]: { $apply: x => ({ active: !x.active}) }
    })
    this.setState({ images });
  }
  render() {
    const { images } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
        { images.map((image, ix) =>
            <Image
              key={ix}
              ix={ix}
              active={image.active}
              clickImage={this.clickImage} />) }
        </div>
    );
  }
};

class Image extends React.Component {
    render() {
    const { ix, clickImage, active } = this.props;
    const style = active ? { border: '1px solid #021a40' } : {};
    return <img
              style={style}
              src={`https://robohash.org/${ix}`}
              onClick={() => clickImage(ix)}/>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And then what it looks like:

[image: Example gif]

Comment: I was assuming you wanted a react answer due to the `reactjs` tag you included.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an event handler for click that adds a "selected" class, then set that selected class to have a border in css.

```css
.selectableImg {
  border: solid 1px transparent;
  margin: 10px;
}

.selectableImg.selected {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<img class="selectableImg"  src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
<img class="selectableImg" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
<img class="selectableImg" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
<img class="selectableImg" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>

<script>
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".selectableImg");
  
  images.forEach(function(i) {i.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    i.classList.toggle("selected");
    })});
  </script>
```