# Hide component when another identical component is shown with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a list of items (`ResultItem`), which have a component inside (`ResultTag`) which when clicked, shows a tooltip above it (a HTML class is added to it and removed when clicked again, to hide it).

However, when I click on `ResultTag`, and then click on `ResultTag` in one of the `ResultItem`'s below it, both show; how would I go about hiding all of the `ResultTag`'s apart from the one I just clicked on, so that only one can show at a time.

Currently, in the `ResultItem`, I have an `onClick` function which sets the state `showTooltip` in the `ResultTag` to false/hidden (using props) whenever the user clicks anywhere within `ResultItem` and the `ResultTag` is visible. However, I need this to work across every `ResultItem`, which means working cross-component.

Here is some simplified code:

```
/* ResultTag */

showTooltip() {
    this.setState({ showTooltip: true })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div onClick={this.showTooltip}>
            {this.renderTooltip()} { /* function which contains the JSX/HTML to show the toolip */ }
            <span className="tag--label">Tags</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Hiding is done in the `ResultItem`, by setting the state and then receiving that as props in the `ResultTag`.

To summarise:

- I have many `ResultItem` components in a list view
- Each `ResultItem` has a `ResultTag` in, which when clicked, shows a tooltip above the tag/label
- When a `ResultTag` is visible, and another one in a different `ResultItem` is clicked, hide all the other `ResultTag`s

Answer (score 1):

You could move the state from within each individual ResultItem into the parent, that way it is centralized in one place and you could enforce logic such that only a certain ResultItem will show its tooltip. You would need to manage the state from within the parent and then pass down a function to each ResultItem (and probably down again into its ResultTag) to handle the click.

I wrote a sample app which shows similar behaviour (although slightly different), I wrote it to demonstrate how to add a border to each item in a list. You can see how I stored the state in the parent and how I passed down the means to read and update it to the children via props. You would of course have to change the logic to enforce only a single item being active, currently it supports any item in the list being 'active'. I wrote it for an answer located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38646533/1515758